# search or convert octal sequences

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have uncompressed a PDF file with pdftk and I am trying to edit it in Emacs with regexp.

The problem is that this file has accented characters and Emacs displays them as octal sequences: e.g. `\340` for à. To edit this file I have two possibilities (at least I think so).

a) Apply an encoding such that Emacs will display actual accented characters and not their octal equivalent. Vim already displays accented characters properly;

b) Search octal sequences with regexps.

As for a), I have tried (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-dos), (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix), (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'raw-text) without success.

As for b), after applying set-buffer-file-coding-system, I am able to incremental search for the octal sequences with the `C-q ... RET`, but I am unable to do what I really need: replacing strings. In fact  `C-q ... RET`, does not match octal sequences when using `M-%` or `C-M-%`.  `` C-x 8 `... `` doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance.
Antonio

Comment: can you upload a sample PDF somewhere?

Comment: Newbie here, hope it is possible to post links. Anyway I just created a one line test file: 
http://www.filedropper.com/test_16 .
In Emacs have a look at line 47 and note how you can manually replace `\340` with à, save and reopen it in your PDF viewer.

Comment: A single high-bit octal character is most certainly not UTF-8.  Try with CP1252 or perhaps CP850.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following key-sequence in the buffer visiting the PDF file:

> <kbd>C-x RET r</kbd> *character-coding* <kbd>RET</kbd>

This will revisit the file using the character-encoding you specify.

Alternatively, if you want to specify the character encoding to use *before* visiting a file, you can do

> <kbd>C-x RET c</kbd> *character-coding* <kbd>RET</kbd>

immediately before typing <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>.

See the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Coding.html) for more details.

Comment: The problem is solved! Thanks 
For the record the encoding is `windows-1252-unix` alias `cp1252-unix` or commonly ANSI with a Unix line-ending. 
Strange is that `(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'windows-1252-unix)` doesn't work, `(revert-buffer-with-coding-system 'windows-1252-unix)` does.
The good is that, with this encoding, it is possible to modify (with regexp) the "uncompressed" PDF, save it and reopen in a viewer and this may be of interest to others. 
It could be still of interest the subject of search-replacing octal codes.

Comment: @antonjo: Why do you say "Strange"?  `C-h f set-buffer-file-coding-system` says clearly: "This means that when you save the buffer, it will be converted
according to CODING-SYSTEM."

Comment: @Stefan I guess it is "strange" because this command is _perceived_ by some users to do something other than what it actually does. What antonjo was looking for was: "I have data in a buffer, some characters are displayed incorrectly. I want a command that re-interprets these characters based on a different character encoding." This is not what `set-buffer-file-coding-system` does, but if it's what the user _expects_, its behavior is perceived as strange. It is a usability issue, a mismatch between the user's mental model of encodings/buffers/files and how Emacs actually handles these things.

Comment: @Thomas: Good point.  I wonder how we could reduce the confusion.  If someone has ideas, please send them via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score -1):

@Stefan

Actually I was not speaking about a difference in saving, but in displaying.

In both cases closing and reopening the file leaves the file as is, with no apparent changes. 
As for displaying, with `(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'windows-1252-unix)` the mode line changes from `(Unix) ---` to `(Unix) **-`, signaling that no change in code system occurred and in fact the characters in the buffer are the same (octal sequences are still there).

When using (revert-buffer-with-coding-system 'windows-1252-unix), mode line changes from `(Unix) ---` to `* (Unix) ---` signaling that the code system has changed to `windows-12**`, according to `M-x list-coding-systems` mnemonic and in fact the octal sequences are displayed with their equivalent accented characters.

If I apply `(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'windows-1252-unix)` to other buffers, for example the scratch, the latter changes from `1\--` to `* (Unix) **`. So for this buffer *there is* an actual and advertised change from `latin-1-dos` to `windows-1252-unix`.

There might well be a coherent design in this, of which I am not aware.

Antonio